# I killed my VPS with putting Firefox to reload the page after 1 second, now one of my domains is dead and gives a 504

Tags: vps

I have one domain on my VPS which I wanted to run a script a few hundred times on to simulate users, so I put a few Firefox tab on refresh every 1 second.

Now that domain is dead, it just gives me a 504 every time I try to go to it, even though I restarted NGINX, PHP and I even shut the server on and off.

All of my other sites on that VPS are Ok and running perfectly, just this one where I tried the reloading on.

What can I do from here?

Answer (score 3):

Your test was really rather pointless because the content will have been cached between the server and yourself. Most probably through multiple caches, including Firefox's own. My guess is that in at least one of those caches the data has become screwed. It's unusual but happens every now and then.

The first step is to flush any and all caches you have control over and then try to access your site.